# NewRelic slowing down server drastically for .NET?

Tags: .net, newrelic, newrelic-platform

We have recently started using NewRelic for our performance measurement but today node in the cluster that had NewRelic installed died because of it. Our system is very busy and each node handles about 15-20k rpm. Only one node had NewRelic installed and while usually 4-10% CPU is used on other nodes, this node (with NewRelic) had about 20-30% CPU usage until today when it jumped to 90%-100%.

I can understand that code injection and profiling uses some CPU, I can even understand 3-5X pefromance degradation when using NewRelic but over 10X performance degradation is just wrong.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I am using .NET4.5, entire system is basically only using HttpHandlers and needs to be quite fast (our APM is usually 0.99 on 200ms), our normal load time is 20ms. This system is analytic tool for websites so needs to be quite fast.

I need to maybe throttle down NewRelic but I don't really understand what to do for this not to happen again except removing it completly.

Also I think one of the biggest problem with NewRelic is that you cannot simply shut it down, even with disabling it in config because it seems that it either remains in memory or something is still hooked to IIS because only uninstall and complete machine reboot worked.

If anyone has any info on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: We ran into issues with NR and discovered some of our code was using .NET 1.x.  I know you mention .NET 4.5, but worth double-checking to ensure no code is using .NET 1.x.  Once we stopped using .NET 1.x, our NR issues cleared up.

Comment: It is not that. We do not even have that version of .NET installed on the machine.

Comment: @lord.fist were you able to fix this issue ? We had the same issue recently